# How to validate the input parameter in a SQL query to avoid SQL-injection?

Tags: sql, validation, code-injection

```
public ResultSet queryResult(Connection con, String query) throws SQLException
{
    Statement s = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet results = s.executeQuery(query);
    return results;
}
```

This method invokes a SQL query built using unvalidated input. This call could allow an attacker 
to modify the statement's meaning or to execute arbitrary SQL commands.

How to validate the input parameters in a SQL query to avoid SQL-injection?

Comment: Use Parameterized statements to prevent sql injection. Raed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

Comment: What kind of input parameters? Your method accepts and runs plain-text sql query. How do you want to validate it?

Comment: @default The result is produced by "FORTIFY STATIC CODE ANALYZER". Also, I have no idea how to validate the input.

Comment: @Leo `This method invokes a SQL query built using` I guess you should show us how this method is called.

Comment: @default Sorry I can't share, it's proprietary. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Leo what? :) ofc, you can simplify your query/code. Change table names, columns, etc. Create equivalent standalone example. Without it your question is too vague to answer. Good luck, anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you work with Java you should use Prepared Statements. A prepared Statement is a precompiled statement (as opposed to dynamic SQL statements). You can define specific points in the statement where you want to insert parameters (called parameter markers the ?, see the example). In your code you can then assign (bind) values to these predefined parameter markers (eg. userid and password in the example). SQL injection is not possible with such a statement.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid=? AND password=?");
stmt.setString(1, userid);
stmt.setString(2, password);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```